# Allow adding data to textbox but not editing with Fabrik on Joomla?

Tags: joomla

I am displaying lists using the Fabrik system with Joomla on my website and want the users to be able to add information to each row but not be able to delete anything. Currently I have it setup so that a user can click the edit button but that allows them to edit all of the data in a large textbox. I just want them to be able to add information to the textbox but not delete pre-existing information. Any help is greatly appreciated! I am using the most recent versions of Joomla and Fabri

Answer (score 0):

Humm if I well understand: not easy (and maybe not advised).

An idea:
A new Calc field recovers and displays the current value from your field.
A Custom PHP in your field (Advanced tab) empties your field. Finally, just after submission a Php Form Plugin changes your field adding the Calc Field concatenated with the new current value from your field.

But really I think it is not advised. Not because Joomla or Fabrik or PHP, but because ... the interest of database applications.

You would prefer to create a linked table, in your List options, Data, Join.
Add your new table as repeatable.
Go in Group, find your original List, find the new group related and set up the options.

I guarantee you that finally you will be able to do what you want, but benefiting from much more possibilities (date of edit, user edit, ACL according to user rights ...).

Answer (score 0):

I would add a second field for new data and create a trigger to add this information to the already existing information upon update of the row